# How to split string with character \ - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, split

I want to split a string into an array of letters, but I have a problem with the special character `\` .

The code:

```js
let s = '\op*Bw'.split('');
```

But I got this result `['o', 'p', '*', 'B', 'w']`, that is not correct because I want the `\` character too in the array.

Comment: You need to escape the backslash to treat it literally.

Comment: This has nothing to do with splitting. If you just do `let s = '\op*Bw'` you'll see that the backslash isn't in the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backslashes '\' escape the next character in the sequence. If you need the '\' in the string, your string will need to look like '\\op*Bw'

```js
let s = '\\op*Bw'.split('');
console.log(s) // ['\', 'o', 'p', '*', 'B', 'w']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `String.raw`

```
String.raw`\op*Bw`.split('')
```